# How does hasNext() and next() work in a while-loop in Java?

Tags: arraylist, hashmap, iterator

This is a simplified version of my code, just to show the logic behind it:

```
while (i.hasNext()){
    hmap1 = i.next();
    if (i.hasNext()){
        hmap2 = i.next();
        bindedhmap = bindhashmaps(hmap1, hmap2);
    }
    else if (!(i.hasNext())){
        newbindedhmap = bindhashmaps(hmap1, bindedhmap);
    }
}
```

Basically, I iterate through hashmaps in an array and combine (bind) them.
Currently, I have 3 hashmaps in an array. The while-loop combines two hashmaps into one, and I have tested that this is correct, but it does not even go to "else if" (I put a print-sentence there to see), so the third hashmap is never combined.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the wrong approach as your "bindedhashmap" always binds the last two elements. It depends a bit on the size of your array, but you should not depend on an `array.length` of 3. You should get familiar with the Stream API which simplifies your problem to a one-liner. See this example, assuming that key and value are both of type String, but works for any type...:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //A lot of initialization and prinitng stuff...
    HashMap<String, String> h1 = new HashMap<>();
    h1.put("foo", "bar");
    h1.put("bar", "foo");
    System.out.println("First: " + h1);
    HashMap<String, String> h2 = new HashMap<>();
    h2.put("foo", "bar");
    h2.put("hello", "world");
    System.out.println("Second: " + h2);
    HashMap<String, String> h3 = new HashMap<>();
    h3.put("", "foo");
    h3.put("world", "hello");
    System.out.println("Third: " + h3);
    HashMap<String, String>[] myArray = new HashMap[] {h1,h2,h3};  //Assuming h1, h2, h3 are inititialized...
    Map<String, String> allTogether = new HashMap<>();

    //This is the really interesting part, stream the array and just add each element to your resulting map!
    Arrays.stream(myArray).forEach(hashMap -> allTogether.putAll(hashMap));
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    System.out.println("Together: " + allTogether);
}
```

If you try, you'll see that your merged map contains 5 elements, one of the source entries is ignored (duplicate key, in a map the key part is a set which doesn't allow duplicates).